# Question about domain of bounded operators

Tags: operator-theory

The definition of a bounded operator is:

An operator $T:X→Y$ is said to be bounded if there exists a positive constant $M$ such that $\left\| {T\left( x \right)} \right\| \leqslant M\left\| x \right\| $, for all $x \in X$

my questions are:

1. When we say for all $x \in X$ does that mean we speaking about $x$ such that $x < \infty$ (crude notation, I mean unbounded elements in the topological space $X$)
2. say I know that $\left\| {T\left( x \right)} \right\| \leqslant M$ for all $x$, could I conclude from this that the operator is bounded

Comment: 1. Depends on if $x \in \lbrace \infty \rbrace$; 2. Of course. You can prove that $T = 0$.

Comment: it is weird to ask for boundedness when you pass unbounded argument, isn't it so?

Comment: The first question makes no sense. $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces here. What does $x<\infty$ even mean?

Comment: @Mark say $X=\mathbb R^n$, do I still need boundedness if I take a vector for which all entries are unbounded?

Comment: The entries of a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ are real numbers. Real numbers are not bounded or unbounded, and the set containing only a single number is always bounded.

Comment: An element of $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a finite sequence of real numbers, so again, there is no meaning to unbounded entries. Anyway, the term of bounded operator is not very interesting in finite dimensions because there any linear operator is bounded. But in infinite dimensions there might be unbounded operators.

Comment: @Mark I think I was just mixing up unbounded as in set theory to unbounded (not of finite size) in the topological sense, but now all is clear, thanks!